# Component not re-rendering in react

Tags: reactjs

```
  const { contacts, getContacts, } = useContext(
    ContactContext
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    getContacts();
    //eslint-disable-next-line
  });

  //prettier-ignore
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {contacts.length === 0 ? (
        <h4 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Please add a contact</h4>
      ): null}
      {contacts.map(contact => (
          <ContactItem contact={contact} />

      ))}
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

`contacts` is initially an empty array and after `getContacts` makes the request to the server, it updates the `contacts` state 
but somehow the words 'Please add a contact' is always showing even after `getContacts()` returns an array with a few contacts. it seems like it does not re-render that part of the component because when the component initially ran, `contacts` was an empty array

Comment: Can you pls add getContacts implementation?

Comment: Where are contacts updated?

Comment: Do you use useState?

Comment: @BudaÖrs, I dont use useState

Comment: @ChithambaraKumar, getContacts calls the server and updates the contexts state with a new array of all contacts

Comment: @MeilechWieder I think useState here would have a great use. Would you like me to explain how to use here useState?

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to "why will/won't my component update", React follows three simple rules.  It will only "re-render" your component if:

- its props change
- its state changes
- its context changes

For those last two it's *critical* that you change them correctly, using the appropriate setter method.  For instance, if you are using state via hooks (vs. class-based state), ie.

```
const [foo, setFoo] = useState('');
```

You *have* to use `setFoo`:

```
setFoo(newValue);
```

If you simply change the Javascript variable:

```
foo = newValue;
```

React has no way of knowing about the change, and so your component *won't* re-render.

While you haven't shown all your code, it seems very likely you're changing your context directly, instead of using the appropriate setter function (as part of a state variable).

P.S. See https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component if you need clarification on the pattern of using state to control context.

Answer (score 1):

Please use hook called `useState`

```
import { useState } from "react";

const { contacts, getContacts, } = useContext(
    ContactContext
  );

  const [state, setState ] = useState({
      contacts:[]
  })

  useEffect(() => {

    setState({
        contact:getContacts()
    })
    //eslint-disable-next-line
  });

  //prettier-ignore
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {state.contacts.length === 0 ? (
        <h4 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Please add a contact</h4>
      ): null}
      {state.contacts.map(contact => (
          <ContactItem contact={contact} />

      ))}
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

the only thing that worked was this, but I don't know why it did not work previously and why it does work now:

```
if(contacts.length === 0 ){
      return <h4>Please add a contact</h4>
}
```

I put this line of code on top of the other return statement